# Запрос к базе данным про критериям

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, telegram-bot

Разрабатываю Telegram-бот "расписание пар" для медвуза. 
**Суть вопроса о помощи:**

---

- Таблица студента состоит из column `chat_id faculty course group`
- Таблица расписания пар состоит из column `number time para auditory faculty course group`

---

**Задача**
Выдавать список пар соответствующих `faculty course group` студента к списку пар.
*Кое что из этого получилось, но если пар на этот день больше одной - не выдаёт*

---

**Что сделано**
Функция, делающая запрос к БД:

```
def check_today(self, chat_id):
with self.conn:
    self.cursor.execute('SELECT course FROM profile WHERE chat_id = %s', (chat_id,))
    self.course = self.cursor.fetchall()[0]
    self.cursor.execute('SELECT "group" FROM profile WHERE chat_id = %s', (chat_id,))
    self.group = self.cursor.fetchall()[0]
    self.today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM schedule_stom WHERE course = %s AND "group" = %s AND date = %s', (self.course, self.group, self.today))
    self.schedule = self.cursor.fetchall()[0]
    list_par = []
    for row in self.schedule:
        list_par.append(row[2])
        list_par.append(row[1])
        list_par.append(row[3])
        list_par.append(row[4])

    return list_par
```

---

**Какая нужна помощь:**
Показать пример правильного SQL запроса и как выводить список, если пар больше одной.

Comment: Код в боте:<br> `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'Сегодня')
def schedelule_today(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пара: {}\n'
                     'Время: {}\n'
                     'Предмет: {}\n'
                     'Аудитория: {}\n'.format(db.check_today(message.chat.id)[0],
                                                db.check_today(message.chat.id)[1],
                                                db.check_today(message.chat.id)[2],
                                                db.check_today(message.chat.id)[3])`

Comment: 1) Переместите факт из комментария в текст вопроса. 2) Замените вербальное описание на CREATE TABLE. 3) Создайте fiddle со структурой таблиц (возможно, упрощённой, без несущественных полей) и тестовым наполнением, и покажите требуемый результат для именно этих данных. 4) Уточните - глобально нужны данные для строго одно студента (заданного по chat_id), некоего набора (несколько значений), всех сразу? Для 2-3 случаев - в данных fiddle должны быть минимум 2 разных студента.

Comment: *Показать пример правильного SQL запроса и как выводить список, если пар больше одной.* Вопрос получения данных и вопрос отображения данных - вещи не связанные. Решите тут только первую задачу, после чего для решения второй создайте новый вопрос.